# Python datetime max and min using numpy showing unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a graph generating code in tkinter. Here in the x-axis I have to show merge value of Date and Time dataframe. But, x-axis doesn't show proper labels to its grid.

Here I am sharing my code as well as excel data and the graph image I'm getting:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import tkinter.messagebox
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
from pathlib import Path

fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('x-small')

root= tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 800, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Data Analyser')
label1.config(font=('Arial', 20))
date1=time.strftime("%H-%M-%S,%d-%m-%Y")

def get1lineGraph ():
      global df

      import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root)
      filename=Path(import_file_path).stem
      isExist = os.path.exists(filename)
      if not isExist:
          os.makedirs(filename)
      df = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
      df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
      daytime=df['Time'].astype(str) + '\n' + df['Date'].astype(str)
      major_ticks_x1 = np.arange(0, len(df.index+1)+3.9, len(df.index+1)/4)
      minor_ticks_x1 = np.arange(0, len(df.index+1)+3.9, len(df.index+1)/8)
      if(df[clicked1.get()].max()==df[clicked1.get()].min()):
          major_ticks_y11 = np.arange(0,14,2)
          minor_ticks_y11 = np.arange(0,14,4)
      else:
          major_ticks_y11 = np.arange(df[clicked1.get()].min(), df[clicked1.get()].max()+3.9, (df[clicked1.get()].max()-df[clicked1.get()].min())/4)
          minor_ticks_y11 = np.arange(df[clicked1.get()].min(), df[clicked1.get()].max()+3.9, (df[clicked1.get()].max()-df[clicked1.get()].min())/8)
      x1 = daytime
      y11 = df[clicked1.get()].astype(float)

      figure11 = Figure(figsize=(11,4), dpi=100)
      subplot11 = figure11.add_subplot(1,1,1)
      t11, = subplot11.plot(x1, y11, color='blue', linestyle='solid', linewidth = 2, label=clicked1.get())
      subplot11.set_ylabel(clicked1.get())
      subplot11.set_xlabel('Date & Time')
      subplot11.set_xticks(major_ticks_x1)
      subplot11.set_xticks(minor_ticks_x1, minor=True)
      subplot11.set_yticks(major_ticks_y11)
      subplot11.set_yticks(minor_ticks_y11, minor=True)
      subplot11.grid(which='both')
      subplot11.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)
      subplot11.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
      subplot11.set_title(clicked1.get()+' VS Time')
      subplot11.legend(loc = 'upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), prop=fontP)
      figure11.tight_layout()
      figure11.savefig(filename+'/Bldg1_'+clicked1.get()+'_'+date1+'.png')
      
      tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Message from Bldg 1.",  "Graph is saved in .png file format in your PC.",parent=root)
      
options1 = [
    "P1",
    "P2",
    "P3",
    "P4"
]
clicked1 = tk.StringVar()
clicked1.set( "Select Y-axis Parameter" )
drop1 = tk.OptionMenu( root , clicked1 , *options1 )
canvas1.create_window(250, 100, window=drop1)

browseButton_Excel1line = tk.Button(root, text='Generate graph with selected Y-axis', command=get1lineGraph, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(500, 100, window=browseButton_Excel1line)

button1 = tk.Button (root, text='Exit from Building 1!', command=root.destroy, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 11, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(400, 180, window=button1)
root.mainloop()
```

Here I am providing excel data for ready to use code making.

```
Date    Time    P1  P2  P3  P4  
1-9-2019    9:57:00 114.33  21.07   21.01   0   
1-9-2019    9:58:00 114.33  21.07   21.01   0   
1-9-2019    9:59:00 6.6 4.63    21.01   0   
1-9-2019    10:00:00    5.72    4.05    21.01   0   
1-9-2019    10:01:00    5.28    4.05    21.01   0   
1-9-2019    10:02:00    5.28    4.05    21.01   0   
1-9-2019    10:03:00    5.72    4.05    21.01   0   
1-9-2019    10:04:00    5.72    3.76    21.01   0   
1-9-2019    10:05:00    5.72    4.05    21.01   0   
1-9-2019    10:06:00    5.72    4.05    21.01   0   
1-9-2019    10:07:00    5.72    4.05    21.01   0   
1-9-2019    10:08:00    5.72    4.05    21.01   0   
1-9-2019    10:09:00    5.72    4.05    21.01   0   
1-9-2019    10:10:00    5.72    4.34    16.82   0   
1-9-2019    10:11:00    5.72    4.34    16.79   0   
1-9-2019    10:12:00    5.72    4.34    16.7    0   
1-9-2019    10:13:00    5.72    4.34    16.79   0
```

Here is the graph I am getting:
[image]

As you can see y-axis working perfectly fine, but x-axis is not giving desired ticks. Last grid of x-axis should provide last daytime of the dataframe.

Like y-axis grid starts from min value and end at max value, likewise I want x-axis value also should start from first index position (which is achieved) and should end at last index position (which needs to be achieved).

Please Help. I'm trying this from last couple of days. But couldn't find the answer.